Recording audio in Unity WebGL game
I am trying to provide recording functionality (save gameplay as video file) for my Unity WebGL game.
I can easily record video stream (via javascript plugin) as
let canvasStream = canvas.captureStream();

But I fail to record audio.
I can go with
stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

But I don’t like this method. It creates popup, interrupting the game. I’d like it to go smoothly, without interruption.
I see the WEBAudio object created on the page with WEBAudio.audioInstances, WEBAudio.audioContext, etc. But I failed to get audio stream from there.
No errors logged and no audio in my recording. Just video.
Appreciate your help and advice on how to get Audio Stream from any of these available objects:
WEBAudio
WEBAudio.audioContext
WEBAudio.audioContext.destination
WEBAudio.audioInstances[1].buffer
WEBAudio.audioInstances[1].getNumberOfChannels()
WEBAudio.audioInstances[2].gain

Thank you.

If it is about the in game audio you could use OnAudioFilterRead (this question shows how to create a wav file from it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710929/unity-creating-folder-on-desktop-then-saving-wav-files-to-it)

Recording audio from where? getUserMedia uses your microphone, that must require the user's consent.

Ask right permissions while starting the session, not in the middle


'OnAudioFilterRead' - one of the 1st things I have tried. Alas, it does not work for WebGL builds.
Besides, this way you have to collect the data sent by 'OnAudioFilterRead' and create blob. Additional spending of the resources.
Apparently there is data buffer and audio stream already hidden in 'WEBAudio' object. It would be great to find how to retrieve it.
My goal is to record the audio that goes to speakers during game play.
One of problems with 'getUserMedia' - it does not work on mobiles.



Permissions - debug shows 'WEBAudio.audioContext.running == true'.
But I'll check permissions handling, thank you.

